# keeping the decimal when creating a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a string of various variables together and I need to pad it with leading zeros AND I also need to preserver the decimal if the value after the decimal is a zero.
If the variable is just a zero, then i want to supress it altogether and pad with spaces

for example:

If I get 0 in variable and it's size is say 3, I want string to be:    "   "
if I get 9 in variable and it's size is say 3, then I want string:     "009"
if I get 90.0 in variable and it's size is say 10, then I want string:  "00000090.0"

I'm trying to use:

```
public function PadField(byval field as object, byval size as int16) as string

   dim fieldstring as string = string.empty
   dim fieldDate as date

   '  here I want to check for a numeric variable
   if isnumeric(field) then

      '  if the variable is an integer with a value of zero...
      if cint(field) = 0 then
         stringField = string.empty.padleft(size,"0")

      '  else if the variable is an integer greater than zero...
      elseif cint(field) > 0 then
         stringField = field.toString.padLeft(size,"0")
      End If

   ' else if a date, I want date to look like MM/dd/yyyy...
   elseif IsDate(field) then
      fieldDate = field
      strigField = fieldDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

   '  else if a string, then I want to pad after with spaces
   else
      stringField = field.ToString.Trim.toUpper.PadRight(size," ")
   End If

   return stringField

end Function
```

The problem is when I pass in a variable like 1234.0, I get the following result:

```
"0001234"
```

but I want:

```
"0001234.0"
```

if I send in 1234.1, then it works and I get  "0001234.1"
if I send in 1 then I want to get "001"
if I send in 90 then i want to get "090"
if I send in a date, I want to get "08/21/2012"
if I send in a string, I want to get "NAME         "

Can anyone help on how to preserver the decimal when the decimal is a zero?

Answer (score 2):

If the number of decimal points change you will have to implement something more elaborate, but if you can live with two decimal points, this will work:

```
           stringField = CDbl(field).ToString("0.00").PadLeft(size, "0")
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce that behavior, Is it possible that your string is being converted to a numeric datatype somewhere?
If I pass in "123.0" to the routine below i get 00000123.0. It looks to me like the problem is somewhere else.

```
Public Sub test(o As Object)
    If IsNumeric(o) Then
        If (CInt(o)) > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(o.ToString.PadLeft(10, CChar("0")))
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As PatFromCanada said, if you pass it in as a string you are fine.  If you are passing it in as integer, it's going to get inferred as an integer, not as a string.  That's not what you want here.